# different web browser get different response when use websocket

Tags: go, browser, websocket

I want connection to a websocket server `wss://fm.missevan.com:3016/ws`。i use online websocket tool `http://www.websocket-test.com` to do it, but in edge browser, it's response is ok and in chrome ,the response is 403 forbidden.

Actually, i use GO language to connection `wss://fm.missevan.com:3016/ws`,I tried many websocket library but all failed.

I checked the request header of connected browser, there are no special fields. so who can analyze the reason of this, thanks

Comment: I do test it, but it always returns `403` header error.

Comment: Can you show your code? From looking at the browser console (with showing requests & XHR enabled) it looks like you need to request `https://fm.missevan.com/api/user/info` to get cookies that are then sent in the websocket request. So extract the `Set-Cookie`-Headers, then send them with the websocket request